# I get error when send PUT request with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, cors, put

I have written HTML and AJAX code to update a camera password in my network. 
When I submit the form I get only

> "error" (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

in Chrome and it does not update the password. But when I try the PUT request with POSTMAN I get `OK(200)` and it updates successfully. Also It works well in Locale (i.e. runing the HTML file from desktop) with Internet Explorer. But after uploading to the server, it does not work with Internet Explorer either (pending and access denied).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://192.168.1.64/Security/users?auth=YWRtaW46MTEK",
        "method": "PUT",
        "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "fda97359-6164-70d0-2896-8ca4804ac06c"
        },
        "data": "<UserList xmlns=\"http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema\" version=\"1.0\"><User xmlns=\"http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema\" version=\"1.0\"><id>1</id><userName>admin</userName><password>TT.123456</password></User></UserList>"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I get this error in chrome. Please see screen shot :

[image: chrome]

"POSTMAN" screen shot :

[image: postman]

Comment: What's the error? Client and/or server side?

Comment: Chrome Extension == Postman? If that's the case, then it's more than likely configuration/logic issue's on the endpoint. It would help displaying the error message too.

Comment: BTW, holy crap, please do something to avoid being able to send invalid XML etc.

Comment: @Dave Newton ,@Tez Wingfield client error. in chrom : https://ibb.co/nvjn15
https://ibb.co/cU9buQ. 
and in firefox:
https://ibb.co/ch5S15
https://ibb.co/nf55ok.
but when send request with Advanced REST Client status OK :
https://ibb.co/kN2kok

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional information-not as off-site links.

Comment: @DaveNewton I Update my question. please answer me. thank you.

Comment: @TezWingfield  I test with POSTMA and update successfull but similar code with ajax in chrom get error. I update my question. please see screen shot.

Comment: I test with internet explorer an work fine, but not work with chrome and firefox

Comment: any one can help me?

Comment: is it intentional to have `function myFunction() {
  function myFunction() {`? I removed one of those and it appears to work as I expect (i.e. `PUT` request) in Chrome and FF ... see [demo phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vfyp-7exk)

Comment: 1) Your API does not support [pre-flighted cross-domain requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Your request is pre-flighted due to the method and headers. 2) Do you even know what the [`crossDomain`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) property does in `$.ajax`? If not, then why are you using it?

Comment: @SamOnela thank you. This was an incorrect typing in question. and in my source code And it's true in the original code. You also used PHP code. Because the information must be sent to the IP address at the user's local area, only Javascript must be used. Unfortunately, still, I get the error that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SamOnela I used the `"crossDomain": true,` because POSTMAN it had used, and it worked properly in POSTMAN. Now I've deleted `"crossDomain": true,`, but I still get the same error. Of course, not working in Chrome is an issue and not working on Internet Explorer from the Internet another issue. Interestingly, though, it works well **on local**  with Internet Explorer, but does not work with Internet Explorer **over the Internet**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a cross-domain request (in the client-side), it will most likely need to be a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request instead of a [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT). According to the MDN documentation for [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> #### Simple requests
>
> Some requests don’t trigger a [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Those are called “simple requests” in this article, though the [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) spec (which defines CORS) doesn’t use that term. A request that doesn’t trigger a [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)—a so-called “simple request”—is one that meets all the following conditions:
>
> - The only allowed methods are:
>
>   - [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)
>   - [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)
>   - [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)</sup>

I ran the code in your post locally, changing the method to [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST). The endpoint needed to have the following headers added:

```
access-control-allow-headers: cache-control,postman-token
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

though the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) could be set to the specific domain instead of `*`. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://intranetHost
```

In the image below, the first XHR request is the pre-flight request (where method is `OPTIONS`) and the second one is the actual request (where method is `POST`)

[image]

Alternatively, if it still needs to be a PUT request, perhaps a request could be made to a sever-side endpoint that would make the PUT request (e.g. using cURL).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests</sub>

Comment: thank you. I test with POST method, But I get the same error. in internet explorer :`"SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied."` and in chrome: `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: Do you have control over the headers sent by the endpoint being called (I.e. 192.168.1.64/Security/users?)? You need to ensure it allows the extra request headers

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the destination device.
But with the code that I wrote in the question, I succeeded on locale and Internet Explorer to change the password. When I transfer code to the Internet it does not work. I think Hikvision camera gives local access only.

Comment: yeah like I mentioned at the end of my answer, you may need to do a server-side request - that would be basically equivalent to the request in Postman; Do you have any server-side scripting capabilities for the site serving the HTML? e.g. PHP, NodeJS, ASP, etc... many of those support cURL or similar technologies

Comment: yeah as I mentioned: you may need to do a server-side request - that would be basically equivalent to the request in Postman; Do you have any server-side scripting capabilities for the site serving the HTML? e.g. PHP, NodeJS, etc...  **Actually**, looking at [the API docs](http://www.datacomtecnologie.it/download/Hikvision/01%20TVCC/02%20Firmware/05%20_Fw%20Terze%20Parti/ONVIF%20CGI%20PSIA/Third%20Part%20Documents/CGI%20protocol/hik_ipmd_v1_5_8.pdf) (presuming it is that) there is no mention of headers *cache-control*, *postman-token* - if you don't pass those headers does it help?

Comment: Hikvision company, in its documents, is not said about the change of password. But in the various articles this tutorial exists That I have tested with PostMan and worked properly. I added PostMan Token to header because, failed change password in Internet Explorer (from local) without it! I can not use server-side scripting. Because the IP of camera is not valid and only from local detected. The script should send commands only from the client.